# What is the difference between babel-plugin-* and babel-preset-*

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am using both plugin and preset and my current react app but technically I am not able to make someone understand what is difference between preset and plugins. For me both are the javascript file which used by babel loader to compile the code.

Comment: Plugins are add-ons to Babel that allow you to transform or use different syntaxes. Presets are just **pre**-bundled **sets** of plugins for specific development purposes. If I were using React, I would use the React preset that *includes a set of plugins* that'll allow Babel to transpile my JSX.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, a babel preset contains multiple babel plugins.

For example, if you only use arrow functions, you only need the `transform-es2015-arrow-functions` plugin. If you use a lot of ES2015 features, you better use `babel-preset-es2015` which contains a lot of plugins including `transform-es2015-arrow-functions`.